# How to hide an element?

Tags: html, css

I’ve been trying to hide this element and I just can’t see where I’m going wrong. I have a wordpress site but one of the pages is nothing but HTML/CSS code. [whatsapp web](https://openweb.onl/whatsapp-web/)

I have the followingcode defined for the site:

```css
div.hideme { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="text-block-2 notredame hideme">All Rebels Rock Shows are NO COVER<br>We pass the hat in support of <a href="https://www.goodshepherdcentres.ca/notre-dame-house" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Notre Dame House</a></div>
</div>
```

The element is still visible, despite the `CSS` class being added.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your HTML snippet is invalid -- there are two closing `div` tags.

There is no issue here. You can see it working in this [codepen][1]. 

Perhaps some other code is missing? Have you linked the stylesheet to the HTML?

  [1]: https://codepen.io/sezna/pen/OJLvRNO

Comment: first: you have 2 x `</div>`. Second: there might be some other CSS overriding it.

Comment: It sounds like you could be hitting a [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Either that or your css is not being loaded. Use the Developer tools in the browser of your choice to inspect the element and see what styles are being applied and what are being over written. If you don't see the class name, your CSS has not loaded, either the path is wrong or thee CSS has been cached (hit ctrl F5 to reload) . If the class is there it should show what is being overwritten and from where.

Comment: Please try to put  "div.hideme { display: none; }"  at the bottom of the CSS file. Otherwise, Might be another CSS is overriding it.... can you please share URL of website for better understanding.

Comment: As you can see from the demo I just converted your code to, the code you've provided works as is. So there is something else applying here. Is this *all* the code you have? Or is there more HTML or CSS at play you haven't shared? We need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Use your browser's inspector to inspect the element. If it is not hidden then you should see your CSS rule that you are sharing here crossed out. Find out which other CSS rule is overriding that. Now you know which CSS selector you need to override. Write a more specific selector and you will be fine.